# Not able to set multiple path variable using powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to set multiple path variables using PowerShell but only the last one is appended.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2', 'User')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2', 'Machine')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Windows\System32", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Windows\System32", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin", "User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin", "Machine")
```

'JAVA_HOME' created successfully.
But in path only last one is appended i.e 'C:\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin'

Comment: Use `[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path')` instead of `$env:Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with this script:

1. When you use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` with any scope other than `Process` it does not update the current process' environment

If you want to set it permanently *and also* affect the current process, you need to call it twice.

2. You're updating the user *and* machine scope with the same values

On Windows, the default process environment variables are built by layering the default user environment on top of the default machine environment. Thus, on the one hand, it's *reduntant* to set the same JAVA_HOME to the same value in both scopes.

3. You're updating the default *PATH* values based on the combined value in the process

Path variables are special. The process values are a *combination* of the user and machine environment. So what's merely redundant in other environment variables can cause real problems with *PATH* variables, since adding a folder to both values results in two copies of it in your process environment path.

Because of that, you should never set the user scope *nor* the machine scope to the value that's in the process, but you should especially not set both of them.

For example:

- If the user value was just "C:\Users\Jaykul\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts"
- And the machine value was just "C:\Windows\System32"
- The process would get "C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\Jaykul\Documents\PowerShell\Scripts"

If you take that, and append something to it, and then set it back to *both*, you're going to get **two of everything** in your new PATH when you start a new process.

#### The right thing to do is:

1. Only modify one scope (the machine scope, *or* the user scope).
2. Update based on the what you're updating.
3. Also update the process scope, so you can tell what's happening.

I have an "Environment" module which is on the PowerShell gallery [and github](https://github.com/Jaykul/Environment) that has a [Add-Path](https://github.com/Jaykul/Environment/blob/master/Source/Public/Add-Path.ps1) function that does all of this, but the basics are:

```
function Add-Path {
  param($Path, [ValidateSet("User","Machine")]$Scope)

  # Update what we were asked to update
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",
    ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $Scope) + [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $Path),
    $Scope)

  # Also update the process scope
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",
    ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Process") +  [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $Path),
    "Process")
}
```

Of course, the function in the module I linked to does more than that, ensuring there aren't dupes, and making sure to insert the new path into the process at the right place (i.e. machine scope before user scope), but that's the basics...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This works for me...

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User") + [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"), "User")